# EF BulkUpdate vs BatchUpdate, BulkSaveChanges vs SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert

Can anyone elaborate the difference between those? I'm very confused. I understand that BatchUpdate should be called directly on DbSet whereas BulkUpdate should be called on DbContext. But **how specifically** are these different? I've seen that performance might vary between those two.

Should I call BulkSaveChanges when I'm doing a BulkUpdate or would usual SaveChanges be enough?

And **yes**, I've seen several questions on SO on the same topic and I still don't understand what's going on there.

I'm talking about https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions library.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can read the documentation. The first article compares BulkUpdate performance to SaveChanges performance, which is weird to me. I understand that doing usual update for a lot of entities with SaveChanges is slow. If you update many entities and call BulkSaveChanges it's quick. What's the point of BulkUpdate then?

Comment: There are no such methods in EF Core (except `SaveChanges` of course). You seem to be targeting some 3rd party library. Please update the question with that info and use the proper tags.

Comment: @IvanYurchenko those aren't EF Core methods. What you link to is a third-party project. We can't guess what those methods do without reading the code. Never mind that something called `BulkSaveChanges` is really weird, since `SaveChanges` already stores all pending changes. From the blurb, it seems that at least the `Insert` methods aren't even related to EF, they're using SqlBulkCopy to insert a bunch of objects. You can do that already if you can convert your objects into an `IDataReader` and *that* is possible using FastMember's `ObjectReader`

Comment: There's no BULK UPDATE or BULK DELETE. Definitely no BULK READ. Most of the blurb is just plain wrong: `BulkRead (SELECT and JOIN done in Sql)` that's what EF does too. It looks like this project works in a way similar to Dapper, using DbContext for medatata. Why not use Dapper directly?

Comment: In fact, [the Bulk Insert code is rather slow](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/EFCore.BulkExtensions/SQLAdapters/SQLServer/SqlServerAdapter.cs#L60) because it creates a copy of the original data as a DataTable. That doesn't scale. [Using FastMember's ObjectReader](https://github.com/mgravell/fast-member#ever-needed-an-idatareader) on the other hand avoids the copy

Comment: As for the rest of the "bulk" methods, it seems the library inserts the data into temporary tables then performs a typical "upsert" - UPDATE the target from the source using an INNER JOIN, INSERT non-existent data with a LEFT JOIN. All this is done using dynamically generated SQL. Entity Framework doesn't seem to be involved beyond supplying the connection and maybe mappings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Those are interesting observations, thank you. Although doesn't EF do the same? I think it fetches the table to memory when updating/deleting entities. Idk why Bulk insert fetches table though, that doesn't make much sense to me. This page and some other comparisons show that there is increase in performance for big amount of entities updated/deleted: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions I haven't checked that out myself yet but it seems reasonable. What do you think?

Comment: No, EF like all ORMs Maps Objects to Relational data, trying to give the impression the application is working with in-memory objects instead of table rows. This works when loading a single graph, ie a root object with associated entities. It breaks down *badly* when working with lots of data, streams of rows or batch operations. There are no objects involved in `DELETE SomeTable where Category=@category`. The package you posted does what I explained earlier, using the DbContext metadata to generate queries. In many cases even that isn't needed.

Comment: Other ORMs like NHibernate allowed executing set-based modifications like `DELETE ... WHERE ...` through their API but EF itself never did. Frankly, this makes applications far more complex than they need to be. All ORMs are leaky abstractions and once you try to deal with sets instead of individual objects, things break down. They're called [The Vietnam of Computer Science](https://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) for good reason. The trick is knowing when to use them and when not

Comment: PS: ORMs were the rage when we thought everything should be object oriented, and data would be just an implementation detail. Turns out data is more important than our applications, and the rage this time is *functional* languages that work on sets of data instead of objects.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apparently I went reading the article you provided and forgot to thank you for all your detailed explanations. These are very useful and mean a lot to me. Thank you so much for being so kind and helping me to figure things out (at least a little bit)!